# Game Theory: Can someone explain the notation used in the definition of "best response"

Tags: notation, game-theory

I am reading a paper which states that that the best response correspondence of a player is mapping:

> $B_i(s_{-i}): S_{-i} \Rightarrow S_i$ such that $B_i(s_{-i}) \in arg\ max_{s_i \in S_i} u_i(s_i, s_{-i})$

In particular:

- $s_{-i}$ denotes vector of all actions for all players except for $i$
- $S_{-i}$ denotes set of all action profiles for all players except
  for $i$

Can someone state in plain words as to what this mapping implies? 
In particular:

- Why is the set of all actions for players except for $i$ is used as
  argument for $B_{i}$?
- What does the $\Rightarrow $ represent?
- Why is $(s_i, s_{-i})$ used as argument for the utility function $u_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $B_i(s_{-i})$ is a best response (or possibly the set of best responses) by player $i$ when the others play $s_{-i}$. In [a collection of game theory notation](http://academics.hamilton.edu/economics/cgeorges/game-theory-files/Notation-Definitions.pdf) the set is called $BR_i(s_{-i})$.  As it is the response to a particular play $s_{-i}$ by the others, it is reasonable for that to be an argument.

I suspect $\Rightarrow$ may just be a substitute for $\to$, so $B_i$ sends an element of $S_{-i}$ to an element of $S_i$.

$u_i(s_i,s_{-i})$ is simply the utility outcome for $i$ when player $i$ uses $s_i$ and the other players use $s_{-i}$, and hence has those as arguments.  It might be possible to read this value in the pay-off matrix.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful. Can you comment on whether the notation used in game theory is more unconventional (read creative) compared to other branch of mathematics?

Comment: Try 1.2.4 of http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2245/GT_notes05.pdf : *"Game theory is “notationally challenged.” Even simple results often use
many more signs and symbols than might have seemed necessary. When
reading a text it is always useful to make your own dictionary: keep a
page to one side where you record the
meanings assigned to symbols in the
text–pay special attention to the meaning of subscripts, superscripts and
decorations."*  It does not help that a lot of game theorist learnt their notation as economists, who I find have a habit of doing strange things with notation.

Comment: As a PhD student in economics who has learned game theory from several professors and now teaches it, I would second Henry's note that notation is often inconsistent (and sometimes quite quirky). A common phrase you'll hear in game theory presentations is "and using a standard abuse of notation...." If you want an intermediate text that is focused on formalism and quite precise in notation, I would recommend "Bill Sandholm's lecture notes - http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~whs/teaching/711/lngt.pdf (which are free online).

Answer (score 1):

- $B_i$ gives the set of player i's optimal (i.e. utility-maximising) actions in response to a given profile of opponents' actions.
- ⇒ denotes a (set-valued) correspondence rather than a (single-valued) function.
- The utility function $u_i$ is one of the primitives of a normal-form game, mapping action profiles (such as $(s_i,s_{-i})$ into real numbers.